# Should I pay the insurance discounted rate or the full rate for an ambulance ride under my deductible?

Tags: united-states, insurance

I had to call recently an ambulance because of a food allergy. By the time I reached hospital, I was okay. Last month, I recieved a bill of 3500 USD. I am just wondering, is it a fair charge? Since my deductible is $5000, I have to pay all this amount. 
I talked to my insurance and they say that the approved rate is only $1100 for this type of service. 
What can I do in this situation, I am ready to pay but this amount seems to be unreasonable. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: FYI: "approved rate" usually is lower than out-of-pocket rate because when the insurance pays, they negotiate a discount.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question but I'm dealing with a similar situation in Dallas.  5 mile ambulance ride, $1,500.  Blue Cross says the ambulance was out of network, will only pay $450.  The kicker is that if I was in a bad car accident and was rendered unconscious then they'd pay the entire amount.  Blue Cross literally told me to maintaina list of in network ambulances and hospitals when I asked how I could avoid this in the future.

Comment: Can this ambulance service accept your insurance?  (Whether in-network or out-of-network). Did you give your insurance information to the hospital/ambulance people to bill your insurance?  It may be that they didn't realize you had insurance? (By the way, sorry!  What a crummy turn of events.)

Comment: @Chelonian, Thanks for reply. The ambulance service does accept my insurance but because of deductable, I am bound to pay the entire amount. Is there a way to know the standard rates or Is there any guidelines for such services? I scoured the internet and found that $1500 is the usual rate in this area. But they are still charging me 2.5 time this rate.

Comment: No, I don't you *are* required to pay the $3,500, but just the approved rate of $1,100. That's what "approved rate" means: the ambulance company has made a deal to honor the rate set by the insurance company. On the Explanation of Benefits (EOB) form you should get from your insurance provider, they should show the original $3,500, then the discount, then your responsibility as $1,100.  Is this not the case?  Did you do this "through" your insurance and get an EOB?  (And yes, this is *even with a deductible*. I have the same exact situation, but still only pay approved rate.)

Comment: @Chelonian: That's what I thought would apply to my medications. Surprise; when I switched to the high-deductable plan I found that the negotiated rates don't kick in until after I have met the deductable. Don't assume; ask your insurer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one source that says "negotiated rate."

> An HDHP is not allowed to pay for anything except preventive care
>   until you have paid the deductible out of pocket. If the plan has
>   negotiated prices with providers (such as an HMO or PPO), you pay only
>   the negotiated price. However, many employer-provided HDHPs make a
>   contribution to your health savings account, so you do not need to
>   come up with the whole deductible out of pocket. (You can also
>   contribute more to the HSA on your own, up to the IRS limit.)
>
> Source: http://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/High_deductible_health_plan

And here's a Reuter's article about how it can be difficult to get through the repricing system to get the negotiated rate even though you are supposed to get the negotiated rate.  I particularly like "Consider any bill from a provider as the beginning of a negotiation rather than like a bill from a plumber or Visa."

> Insurance companies put every claim through a repricing engine, where
>   they figure out the difference between what the provider charges and
>   the negotiated discount rate - and that is supposed to happen even if
>   you have not met your deductible.
>
> Yet sometimes people get bills from doctors and pay them without
>   thinking about it.
>
> "Consider any bill from a provider as the beginning of a negotiation
>   rather than like a bill from a plumber or Visa," advises Dudik.
>
> And sometimes the repricing never happens. Pat Palmer, founder of
>   Medical Billing Advocates of America, says she has seen cases where
>   insurance companies did not bother to put bills through repricing,
>   since they were not paying them anyway.
>
> "They take whole amount and apply it to deductible, and they neglect
>   to put on the explanation of benefits that there is a different amount
>   that you should be paying," Palmer says. "We have had some insurance
>   companies tell us that 'it costs us money to put a claim through
>   repricing, so we just process the claim.'"
>
> That simply goes against Humana's policy, Smithson says. His advice to
>   customers for avoiding all billing problems: Stay in-network whenever
>   possible, because the insurer has a closer relationship with those
>   providers and can exert more control over billing practices.
>
> Source: http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/11/26/us-usa-health-billingmistakes-idUSBRE9AP0U320131126

And another example of how someone has to take extra steps to get the negotiated rate.

> People often roll their eyes at the mention of a
>   high-deductible health plan.  “You pay $5,000 before insurance covers
>   anything?”  They don’t see the benefit of such a plan – especially
>   since I’m not likely to use anywhere near $5,000 in medical services
>   in a typical year.  Then I explain the benefits of insurance
>   negotiated pricing.  I can walk into my doctor, present my card, and
>   arrange for my insurance to be billed.  Yeah, I understand that
>   eventually the bill will come back to me (without my insurance paying
>   a dime), but the wonderful thing is that it is usually 40-60% cheaper
>   than when I first walked in.  My insurance company can use their
>   pre-contracted rates to get me savings I might not have had on my own.
>   (Note:  It is possible to ask your doctor to bill you at a negotiated
>   rate, but they don’t have to.  By sending it through your insurance,
>   you are guaranteed their contracted rates, plus you get an additional
>   30-60 days to get your finances in order until the bill comes.)
>
> Source: http://www.wisebread.com/why-i-heart-my-high-deductible-health-insurance-plan

Comment: +1. We get billed only the negotiated rate for everything, by staying in-network and by having everything submitted to insurance.

Comment: +1. The OP's insurance company is almost certainly only crediting the OP with the *negotiated amount* towards the deductible, so the OP better only pay the negotiated amount!